# software update available -- how to find out the details?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, ota-update, htc-chacha

My UK HTC Chacha phone running 2.3.5 since the last few months shows a notification since the last couple of days that there is a software update available. But the menu only says that it's a bit over 7MB to downloads, it doesn't specify what software update this is which version  -- how to find out the details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your carrier is responsible for sending OTA updates.  Check their website, call them and ask, or try searching for your carrier's name and "Android update".

Answer (score 0):

The ChaCha does the actual updates check by contacting some webservers (*.htc.com) which are listed in build.prop. All released ROM updates are listed at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2094100 but with a 7MB download it must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

The over 7MB to download part could be that the phone is set in a way that downloading files >7Mb would require a Wi-Fi connection.

To avoid data wastage many phones have this feature to enable warning/limit downloads over the mobile data usage. This settings can be managed under the settings options of your Mobile Data option.

Just by un-checking the option you can easily download the update OTA