# How do you find out what changes there are in new firmware?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-2, device-firmware

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 running ICS 4.0.3. It has desktop software with it called Kies for managing the phone and when I plugged it in today it told me that there was new firmware available:

> Current firmware version: PDA:LPB / PHONE:LPB / CSC:LPC (TMU)
>
> Latest firmware version:  PDA:LPD / PHONE:LPB / CSC:LPD (TMU)

How do I find out what changes there are in the new firmware version? I'd rather not make any changes to my phone (which is already flaky enough after the upgrade to ICS) without knowing what the changes are.

Plugging the firmware string into Google produces only a few results and none of them explain what the update contains.

A [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23286/software-update-available-how-to-find-out-the-details) suggests checking with my carrier's website but that only produced [one result](http://support.t-mobile.co.uk/discussions/index?page=forums&topic=801018181e6a55013882cf7614007ebf&nofilter=y)(*) which I had already found via Google. It is a person saying they did the upgrade, thinking it was 4.0.4 but it wasn't. That page doesn't help me to understand what the changes are.

So to reiterate the question, **how do I find out what changes there are in the new firmware version?**

---

Similar question: [What's in an update?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17472/whats-in-an-update)

---

**UPDATE**

Looking as samfirmware.com as mentioned in the comments and answer, I can see that T-Mobile released two firmwares with the lable 4.0.3:

```
GT-I9100 - United Kingdom (T-Mobile)
PDA: I9100BVLPB
CSC: I9100TMULPC
Version: 4.0.3
Date: 2012-04-10
Regions:

GT-I9100 - United Kingdom (T-Mobile)
PDA: I9100BVLPD
CSC: I9100TMULPD
Version: 4.0.3
Date: 2012-05-25
Regions:
```

The first is the one I have and the second is the one on offer. Apart from what is written there, I could find no further information on that site about what they might contain. (*As an aside, I think that's a useful website and should come in handy in the future*)

Comment: Not all manufacturers are open about what changes made, its usually along the PR lines of "minor bug fixes", might be best to check on [samfirmware](http://samfirmware.com) on their forums...

Comment: @t0mm13b lol, I just spent one hour reading to reach that website... I must pay better attention to the question updates! :)

Comment: @Zuul heh! yeah, would be surprised what is out there on the intertubez ;) xda is another source but its awful since the recent facelift on that site and resembles geocities to me... :P :D

Answer (score 2):

## Firmware update

A firmware update usually brings to your device bug fixes or new features. This is good because insures your device security and readiness for a stable usage.

---

After spending one hour trying to find a changelog for Samsung firmwares, the best I could came up with was this website:

[SamFirmware](http://www.sammobile.com/firmware/)

> What is this? The firmware page of SamMobile is specially for the die-hard Samsung owner.

Since firmware are country related, and I don't know yours, you can try to locate the firmware there:

**Your new version:**

> PDA:LPD / PHONE:LPB / CSC:**LPD** (TMU)

<sup>Marked at bold what's relevant to find that firmware.</sup>

Enter LPD in the search box and look at the column "CSC", than locate the row with the firmware released for your country.

**Note:** Nonetheless, there's not much information available.

---

**There's also:**

This two websites provide a comprehensive list of the firmwares released:

- [Samsung Galaxy S2 Firmware Updates via Kies Official Releases compiled list](http://devsrom4android.blogspot.pt/2011/10/samsung-galaxy-s2-firmware-updates-via.html)
- [How To Update Samsung I9100 Galaxy S II Firmware](http://phone56.blogspot.pt/2012/05/how-to-update-samsung-i9100-galaxy-s-ii.html)

---

### Locate your current firmware

1. Touch Menu;
2. Touch Settings;
3. Scroll to and touch About phone;
4. The software version will be displayed.

   [image: Samsung Galaxy S II - About Phone]

Comment: Thanks for the information about updating firmware but that was not what I was after. I know what a firmware update is and its purpose (I even make reference to upgrading to ICS). I went to samfirmware.com as suggested and have updated the question with the information from there. The second link you gave only listed firmware numbers and didn't actually have the LPD version listed. The third link was about how to do an update and therefore not relevant to the question. I'm from the UK by the way if that helps.

Comment: @BurhanAli By your current firmware I already knew that you were from UK, and that's about it when we talk about firmware detailled information! There's no comprehensive and detailed information about every firmware released and what changes do they carry when compared to the previous version. That's the reason as to why my answer provided a broad overview on this subject and I've mentioned that "there's not much information available." on it.

Comment: @BurhanAli I will dig deeper into this matter and try to locate more intelligence on this subject. I will return to update the answer with the new findings. **PS:** I to would like to have a revision history for firmware updates, since I have it for other pieces of hardware that I don't even update :D